# rake aborted! undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, rails

In a fresh new Ubuntu machine, I have installed ruby with

> sudo apt-get install ruby1.8

and then installed rubygem1.8 with :

> sudo apt-get install rubygems

and after that installed rails3.2.8 with :

> gem install rails

The procedure was very simple. But here comes the problem. When I tried checking the version of rake with `rake --trace -version` I got the following error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `rsion' for #<Rake::Application:0xb72c731c>
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:316:in `standard_rake_options'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1298:in `eval'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:316:in `standard_rake_options'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1298:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1298:in `parse_in_order'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `catch'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `parse_in_order'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1248:in `order!'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1339:in `permute!'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1360:in `parse!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:425:in `handle_options'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:74:in `init'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `init'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:64:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
```

Is it the problem due to I have installed straight from ubuntu apt-get package manager ?

Comment: did my answer help you or was the single dash just a typo in your question?

Comment: Was a typo, indeed. thank you for your help though. I have accepted it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake --version` will output the rake version you have installed. Or in short style: `rake -V`. See the documentation for rake (read below on how to do that).

You used a single dash in front of a long style command. **If you use a single dash, all following letters will be treated as individual command line options**.

For example 
`rake -h` will show you a list of possible command line options and 

`rake -Vvt` prints out the version of rake, activates message logging to standard output and enables tracing with full backtrace. That means, the combined short style options -V, -v and -t are passed to the programm. In your case, you tried to execute rake with the options -v, -e, -r, -s, -i, -o and -n. That worked for -v (verbose) and -e (execute code), but rsion could not be found.

`rake --Vvt` would search for an option with the name Vvt, and `rake --version` searches for an option with the name version.

Be aware that this is all convention, it's up to the programmer to obey these or net. To get a list of all documented command line options of your programm use 
`man programm` for the manpage and `programm -h` or `programm --help` for a short documentation, replace "programm" with, for example, rake, to see the options for rake.